# Getting slices for various Stack and Boxed types

Tags: rust, hash, heap-memory, slice

I'm working on some data structs that require some data to have Order (a AVL), instead of having to force the user to implement a method like `.hash()` i want to use Blake3 hash.
the problem is that the hasher requires a slice of u8 to work.

I found this function that gives me the desired slice

```
unsafe fn as_u8_slice<T: Sized>(p: &T) -> &[u8] {
    core::slice::from_raw_parts(
        (p as *const T) as *const u8, 
        core::mem::size_of::<T>()
    )
}
```

I got this code from a stack overflow question but i cant find the link :(

This work exactly like I want for `stack` only variables, but for `Box` elements like string this function gives me a slice to the "metadata" of the string instead of the content. is there a way to have a "generic" function gets me a slice from the heap data in data types that use it.
And how would it interact with Boxed structs?

Comment: This function is unsound.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing *is* the `Hash` trait. You should use it for this situation. You can use `Hash` with any hash function that implements the [`Hasher`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hasher.html) trait, so if you want to use a different hash function, you just need a different implementer of `Hasher`.

Answer (score 0):

As structs' [layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/vec/vec-final.html) is defacto an implementation detail, you can't rely on anything except the traits it provides. So, if you want some behavior from the argument of type `T`, you need [to bind](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#trait-bound-syntax) the trait with the type:

```
fn do_smth<T: AsRef<[u8]>>(p: &T) {
  let slice: &[u8] = p.as_ref();
}
```

So this function can be applied to all the variables, whose type implements [`AsRef<[u8]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html). In the same fashion, you may require some behavior from the elements of the AVL tree, like this:

```rust
pub struct AVLTree<T> {
  root: Box<Node<T>>
}

impl<T: Ord + Hash> AVLTree<T> {
  pub fn insert(&mut self, val: T) {
    // may call val.cmp() and hash methods
  }
}
```

It is hard to implement a universal hashing through `&[u8]` as there are data types (linked lists, or `Box<Box<Box<...>>>`) that are sparse. But one can implement the `Hash` trait for these types.